# How do I say ''Idle animation'' in Japanese?

Tags: words, word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to know how to say the term ''idle animation'' in Japanese. It's what a character from a videogame does when standing still for too long. Ex: Sonic.

I have seen people in twitter use ''アイドルアニメーション'', but I wonder if it is the correct term.

Comment: Sorry, [we don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628)

Comment: Sorry. I actually wanted to ask a Japanese developer about a feature of their game via Twitter, where I would bring up the Idle Animation of a character. I have seen people in twitter use ''アイドルアニメーション'', but I wonder if it is the correct term.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question, asking about which term is more readily understood or something like that.

Comment: Phrase requests like this are accepted only if you have clearly shown your previous research effort. I think you have done it in your comments, but it should be in the body of your question. Next time please use the "edit" function so that your question will include enough information.

Comment: アイドルアニメーション is indeed a confusing way of putting it because アイドル in Japanese tends to refer to so-called pop "idols".

Answer (score 3):

> 待機{たいき}モーション

... is the common word used to describe idle animations.